# How do you conduct a search of your own questions?

Tags: support, search

I would like to search through question I've asked to see if certain keywords are present in my question title and/or content. Is this possible? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use searchy keys combination flavour power.

If you want to narrow to the keywords only appearing in the title:

> [intitle:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intitle%3A1)

If you want to show up your posts:

> [user:me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame)

Let's say you want to search for "passwords" in question titles you've posted in:

> [user:me intitle:1 passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+intitle%3A1+passwords)

Which can be a little restrictive since you're zeroing on the title only. But if you're on the hunt for your posts where you mention "hash"

> [user:me hash](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hash)

Just mix and match and you're on your way to better searching through Stack Overflow.